# Android: how to put question mark in a string resource?

Tags: android

Android doesn't allow strings containing '?' because it has special meaning in XML context. How do I encode this symbol in a string resource?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use a backslash.

[Read more about escaping characters here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling)