# force string res with placeholder to show the punctuation directly after the placeholder

Tags: android

So here is a simplified approximation of my situation:

I have a string res as this:

```
<string name="greeting">Hello, are you %1$s?</string>
```

and I use getString(resId, Object...) like this:

```
String name = "Bill";
getString(R.string.greeting, name);
```

and this produces the string "Hello, are you Bill" (without the '?')

My question is how do I force it to show the ? at the end without having and spaces or anything between the name and the ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268464/android-how-to-put-question-mark-in-a-string-resource

Comment: Use a backslash `\?`

Comment: ok so I didn't change anything, compiled again and ran it and now it shows...  I'm confused...

Comment: the post about android not allowing '?' in the strings is bs in my opinion because I have been using '?' in strings all over the place and this is the first time I have had any issue with it.